# How to enable autocomplete (IntelliSense) for python package modules?

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, pygame, intellisense

*This question is not about Pygame, I'm usin Pygame as an example.*

While experimenting with Pygame I've noticed that autocomplete is not working for some modules. For example, if I start typing `pygame.mixer` autocomplete shows `MissingModule`. While searching for a solution I've found a lot of similar questions for various text editors and modules that have parts written in C. I am using Visual Studio Code, python path is set correctly and my code runs fine.
One strange workaround is modifying Pygame's `__init__.py`[image] 
What's the right way to enable autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, but I would appreciate some explanation from someone more experienced with Python:

```
import package.module as module
```

With Pygame mixer it's:

```
import pygame.mixer as mixer
```

[image]

But I still don't understand why autocomplete for `import.package.module` doesn't work, but `import.package.module as module` does.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `pygame.mixer` doesn't work with `import pygame` because there is no attribute `mixer` inside `pygame` **package**. If attribute is not there autcomplete won't list it.

When you import package, Python doesn't recursively import subpackages and modules unless it's explicitly assigned inside the "__init__.py" file inside a package.

This is why `import pygame.mixer as mixer` works because you import `pygame` package **and** `mixer` module(?) which is available through local name `mixer`. However with such import you don't have `pygame` available in local scope.

Similar situation is when you just `import pygame.mixer`. `pygame` is available but `mixer` has to be referenced by `pygame.mixer`.

In both cases `pygame` package and `pygame.mixer` module(?) are executed.

You could also use `from pygame import mixer` instead `import pygame.mixer as mixer` or `from pygame import mixer as module` if you want to rename.

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
**from pygame import ***

Now you can see nested autocompletion options.